# Conditional Breakpoint if a memory address contains a specific value in hexadecimal in GDB

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, embedded

I want to be able to break program execution in debugging when a memory address per double-word contains a specific value in a hexademical format.

Consider the following scenario:

**(gdb) x/12dwx $pc**

```
0x80327a9e: 0x00108fbf  0x00008fb0  0x10212883  0x100b0000
0x80327aae: 0x00080083  0x001803e0  0x54db27bd  0x00000c0c
0x80327abe: 0x9ea70000  0x2021080c  0x001c0040  0xffe88ca4
```

I want to watch for the value `0x9ea70000`, so that the execution stops at memory address `0x80327abe`.

Comment: `(gdb) help watch`

Comment: `break if` ........

Comment: You can set the condition on a watch point, please see the 'watchpoint commands' section on this [page](https://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)

Comment: The watch is for watching a specific variable? Here i want to watch for basically all memory addresses (virtual address space) if one particular memory address contains a specific value. Maybe you do a loop over the entire address space and set a break if ? Is that possible?

Comment: "I want to watch for the value 0x9ea70000, so that the execution stops at memory address 0x80327abe" -- your question makes no sense: if address `0x80327abe` contains data, then execution never passes that address. And if that address contains code, then the value at that address should never change.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is actually the section where data is stored so the execution never passes. Is the only possible way to watch for a value on an address that contains data, to dump the address values and do search on the dumped data or do we have a technique in gdb?